# How to skip directly to page x of n in a long list of search results?

Tags: support, user-interface, search, navigation

It would be very helpful if one could go directly to a specific page number when the number of pages returned for a search is very large, but I am unable to figure out if it possible and nothing pops up to tell me if the question has already been dealt with in this forum.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way in the interface, but  you can edit the URL directly.

For example, search for "group" and click to get to the second page then the URL is something like this

`https://math.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=Newest&q=group`

Note the `page=2`, change the `2` to whatever page you want.

This not specific to search, but also works on other types of pages.

Comment: Neat.  That works just as well!  Cheers, Nick